# Cannot access variables outside scope in browser context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Using `protractor` for angular e2e tests. I have a scope problem with the `addMockModule`. The spec states:

> The JavaScript to load the module. Note that this will be executed in
>   the browser context, so it cannot access variables from outside its
>   scope.

https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule

```
browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {
  angular.module('modName', []).value('foo', 'bar');
});
```

Problem: I am trying to pass another function `Mockr` to my mock module. I want to set and get a mock id.

**steps.js**

```
var mockData = require('../../mocks/data.js');
var Mockr = require('../../mocks/mockr.js');

var steps = function() {
  this.Before(function(scenario, done) {
    browser.addMockModule('httpBackEndMock', mockData.module, Mockr );

    done();
  });

};

module.exports = steps;
```

**data.js**

```
exports.module = function ( Mockr ) {
  angular.module('httpBackEndMock', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .run(function($httpBackend) {
     // cannot access Mockr here... 
     // since this is in browser context scope,
     // how can I access Mockr???
     // like: Mockr.getMockId();
  });
};
```

**mockr.js**

```
module.exports = {
    id: 5,
    setMockId: function(id) {
        module.exports.id = id;
    },
    getMockId: function() {
        return module.exports.id;
    }
};
```